# How can I get WebStorm to automatically detect Remote URLs for JavaScript files when debugging?

Tags: meteor, webstorm

Right now, I need to manually specify a Remote URL for each file - see below:

[image: Screenshot from Debug configuration]

I'm using Meteor, and I suspect it is because Meteor appends a query string to the URL as below:

> http://localhost.example.com:3000/client/templates/js/contextMenuBin.js?9cc0534f8fe5e349431ed0247e98967b42711dc2

Is there some way to tell WebStorm to ignore the query string, or to tell Meteor not to append a query string?

I'm using an early access version of WebStorm 6 - see below:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried specifying it for a whole folder instead of individual files?

Answer (score 0):

LazyOne's suggestion works - specifying the URL at the folder level let's WebStorm find any Javascript files below it:

[image]

Obvious, but also not so obvious, especially since WebStorm prompts you for the URL for the file explicitly:

[image]